# Handle Exception after all lines have been finished execution

Tags: java, exception

I need methodC2 also gets executed even though there is an exception by methodC1(). Here I have added only two methods as methodC1() and methodC2(). Let's say there are many methods. In that case also, the solution should be able to applicable.

```
    abstract class A {
        abstract String methodC1() throws ExceptionE;
        abstract String methodC2() throws ExceptionE;

        protected String methodA() throws ExceptionE2 {
            try {
                methodC1();
                methodC2();
            } catch (ExceptionE e) {
                 throw new ExceptionE2();
            }
        }
    }

    class C extends A {
        String methodC1() throws ExceptionE {
            // do something
        }

        String methodC2() throws ExceptionE {
             // do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: what if `methodC2` throws a different exception than `methodC1`?

Comment: Put it in finally block.

Comment: Use try catch in each method's implementation and handle it there only or use try catch for each method while calling the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
protected String methodA() throws ExceptionE2 {
try {
    methodC1();
} catch (ExceptionE e) {
    throw new ExceptionE2();      // HERE
} finally {
    try {
        methodC2();
    } catch (ExceptionE e) {
        throw new ExceptionE2();  // THERE
    }
}
```

If `methodC1` and `methodC2` both throw exceptions, the `ExceptionE2` that propagates from `methodA` is the one by thrown within the `finally` block; i.e. `// THERE`  The first (thrown `// HERE`) gets "eaten".

There are other ways of dealing with this requirement, but this one is simplest, and doesn't entail changing the signatures of `methodC1` and `methodC2`.

---

If you need to propagate an exception that encodes the error information from both `ExceptionE` exceptions, then you are going to need to redesign `ExceptionE2` so that it can wrap multiple exceptions.  (It is not possible for two exceptions to be propagated simultaneously in Java ... or any other programming language I know of.)

The end result might look like this:

```
protected String methodA() throws ExceptionE2 {
    List<ExceptionE> exceptions = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        methodC1();
    } catch (ExceptionE e) {
        exceptions.add(e);
    }
    try {
        methodC2();
    } catch (ExceptionE e) {
        exceptions.add(e);
    }
    if (!exceptions.isEmpty()) {
        throw new ExceptionE2(exceptions);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't want to recover from an exception for the same method.

If you really need to do that you can pack your "many" methods to other methods if you can so that they maybe share the business logic and exception handling. 
For example a method maybe should not run if above failed.

Also you can have each method with in its own try catch so it can continue execution.

Or you could make a list of executions to execute them in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `throws ExceptionE`instead use try catch block on methodC1 and methodc2.

```
abstract class A {
    abstract String methodC1 ();
    abstract String methodC2 ();

    protected String methodA (){
        methodC1();
        methodC2();
    }
}

class C extends A {
    String methodC1 () {
       try{
           //code
       } catch (ExceptionE e) {
           //handle exception
       }
    }

    String methodC2 () {
       try{
           //code
       } catch (ExceptionE e) {
            //handle exception
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Finally block to your try-catch should solve your problem. Finally is called no matter what the result of the operation in the catch block was.

```
try{
    methodC1();
}
catch(ExceptionE e){
    throw new ExceptionE2();
}
finally{
    methodC2();
}
```